# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

My project is divided into 4 modules

> commmon https://pastebin.com/EiRL7Snk (build.gradle)
>
> core https://pastebin.com/n1b1xWMb (build.gradle)
>
> web https://pastebin.com/9CCrA9q0 (build.gradle)
>
> app https://pastebin.com/uEHZDrmQ (build.gradle)

and the main `build.gradle` file for the project https://pastebin.com/xbazbg5U

When you click the `build` button for the `app` module to build the application I'm getting errors

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':common:compileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:.
  Required by:
      project :common
> Could not find org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:.
  Required by:
      project :common
```

and during synchronization e.g.

```
Warning:
    root project 'REST-Web-Services': Unable to resolve additional project configuration.
    Details: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':core:compile'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:.
Required by:
    project :core
```

After entering the `Gradle` tab in IntelliJ and displaying the dependencies of the modules, I get the underlined erroneous dependencies without the version

> common https://zapodaj.net/002015941d147.png.html
>
> core https://zapodaj.net/2c9929a99daed.png.html
>
> web https://zapodaj.net/db09241a806ad.png.html

Importing these dependencies also will not work https://zapodaj.net/5659d080d6a95.png.html

Dependencies are without a version and therefore cause an error. What is going on. After all, I have given repositories. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The common project has no dependency management for `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind` so the `io.spring.dependency-management` plugin can't set a version before gradle tries to resolve the dependency

Comment: In the Netflix project, a similar solution to my works https://github.com/Netflix/genie/blob/master/build.gradle#L65 https://github.com/Netflix/genie/blob/master/genie-common/build.gradle

Comment: But genie has this line: https://github.com/Netflix/genie/blob/master/build.gradle#L76

The `platform-bom` contains a managed version for `jackson-databind`